# Expression "that comes with it" - correct?

Tags: german, come

as a German native speaker, I wonder whether the following sentence is correct:

"The text deals with inflation and the problem for young people that comes with it."

"(...) comes with it" sounds like a wrong 1 to 1 German-English translation to me. Is it correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> The text deals with inflation and the problem for young people that comes with it.

The sentence is understandable and should not cause any confusion; readers should know that
*that comes with it* refers to *problem*.

Edit After @FumbleFingers' Comments

I would, however, prefer

> The text deals with inflation and the *problem**s** that **come** with it* for young people.

Comment: Nobody really cares whether it's singular or plural problems in reality, but idiomatically [we nearly always pluralize ***problems*** in such contexts.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+the+problem+that+comes%2Cand+the+problems+that+come&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)

Answer (score 0):

"come with" is a somewhat colloquial version of "accompany", which is neutral, shading into formal. It is often the case that the Latinate word will be in a somewhat more formal register than the Germanic one.